# Select TD under TH

Tags: xpath

I have next table:

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Created By</th>
        <th>Modified</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mr. John</td>
        <td>COMPLETE</td>
        <td>PENDING</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mr. Lorem</td>
        <td>COMPLETE</td>
        <td>COMPLETE</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

1. How to select TD with `COMPLETE` status under `Status` TH?
2. How to select TR with `COMPLETE` status under `Status` TH?

Answer (score 1):

> How to select TD with COMPLETE status under Status TH?

```
//td[
  normalize-space() = 'COMPLETE' and 
  count(preceding-sibling::td) = count(
    ancestor::tbody/tr/th[normalize-space() = 'Status']/preceding-sibling::th
  )
]
```

> How to select TR with COMPLETE status under Status TH?

I'll leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Does it exist more simple xpath?

Comment: Not if your don't want to hard-code the column number. If you can predict the column number you can replace the part that calculates the column position.

Answer (score 0):

With your table as :

```
Created |  Modified | Status
----------------------------
Mr.John  COMPLETE     PENDING
Mr.Lorem COMPLETE     COMPLETE
```

and from your questions 1. and 2.

You want for 1 : `//table/tbody/tr/td[3][.='COMPLETE']`

for 2 : `//table/tbody/tr/td[3][.='COMPLETE']/parent::tr`

Comment: Nope. You use `TD` index. Not `TH` value. And I need to find `COMPLETE` under `Status` TH.

Comment: `And I need to find COMPLETE under Status TH` : The COMPLETE under Status TH is not a TD ??

Comment: Yes, but you use `td[3]` with index and it is not linked to `Status` TH